# VB.net global actions

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

I am writing an application in VB.net (using Visual Studio 2022) which has a lot of text boxes. I am wondering if there is a way to write a routine so any time any of the textboxes have the "enter" action called it will highlight the text contained in the textbox, as opposed to writing the code for each individual textbox "enter" routine?

Comment: `enter action`? Enter keyboard key? Enter event? You can have a single event handler for all of them. Or create a custom `TextBox` and override the relevant methods and/or properties to produce/perform the required effect/action...etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that *"have the "enter" action called*" means when it receives focus, the simplest option would be to create your own custom control that includes that functionality, then use that control instead of regular `TextBoxes`. Creating custom controls is pretty simple when you want to add to an existing control rather than start from srcatch.

```vb
Public Class TextBoxEx
    Inherits TextBox

    Protected Overrides Sub OnEnter(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnEnter(e)
        SelectAll()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Once you have that class in your project, it's just a matter replacing existing `TextBox` refrerences in the designer code with that class. If your project targets .NET Framework, you'll have to *Show All Files* in the *Soluion Explorer* to access the designer code file. The designer code for a form with a `TextBox` will look something like this:

```vb
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'TextBox1
        '
        Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 12)
        Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
        Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(100, 20)
        Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(800, 450)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)
        Me.PerformLayout()

    End Sub

    Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As TextBox
End Class
```

You just need to replace this:

```vb
Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As TextBox
```

with this:

```vb
Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As TextBoxEx
```

and this:

```vb
Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
```

with this:

```vb
Me.TextBox1 = New TextBoxEx()
```

You can even use the *Find & Replace* functionality in VS to find all the instances you need to replace. Once that's done, everything else is automatic.

Just be sure to have backed up your code before messing with the designer files, in case you break them. Of course, you should be using source control so you should just be able to undo changes to go back to your last good code.

Comment: FYI: The base class calls the `SelectAll()` method in the [`OnGotFocus`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/TextBox.cs,629) method override. So, creating a custom `TextBox` to do the same thing is pointless.

Comment: @dr.null, if that's so, `OnGotFocus` must only be executed the first time a `TextBox` gets focus. If you set the `Text` property of a `TextBox` in the designer, the entire text will be selected the first time that `TextBox` gets focus. Once you change that though, the `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` properties will be persisted as the control gets and loses focus. If you want the entire text selected every time then that will not happen automatically and that is what the above code does. Maybe I misinterpreted but I thought that that is what the OP wanted.

Comment: No problem Johni, just something to share.

Comment: @dr.null, just followed your link to check out the source. That logic does single out the first time the control gets focus so we do need the extar code if we want that behaviour on every focus.

Comment: Right, hopefully `enter action` means what we are talking about here. I don't know.